# Update multiple background-position on scroll using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The parallax script doesn't update the css on `$(window).scroll`. It seems like you can not add multiple background-positions with jQuery?

**Parallax scroll script:**

```
<script>
var top_header = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
  top_header = $('header');
});
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var st = $(window).scrollTop();
  top_header.css({'background-position':"left "+(st*.5)+"px,"});
});
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
header {background-image: url(../images/1.png), url(../images/2.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
        background-position: left, right; 
        height: 550px; width: 100%}
```

**I've tried to update the css like this:**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var st = $(window).scrollTop();
  top_header.css({'background-position':"left "+(st*.5)+"px,"+","+"right "+(st*.5)+"px,"});
});
```

This brakes the code and the header's background-position doesn't update on scroll as it should.

Any ideas appreciated.

[Working example](http://bjorelid.se/gbctest/working/working.html)
[Not working example](http://bjorelid.se/gbctest/notworking.html)

Comment: no, css doesn't support 'multiple background images', use 2 divs (display:inline-block) with a background each

Comment: @andrew Of course it [does](http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/).

Comment: @dfsq oh well, i stand corrected, didn't know that

Comment: css3 support multiple background images. please read docs: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In css you set [multiple background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds) position like this:

```
 background-position: bottom right, left, right;
```

that means your code shall look some how like this

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var st = $(window).scrollTop();
  top_header.css({'background-position':"left "+(st*.5)+"px," + "right "+(st*.5)+"px;"});
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've described that I've already tried in the question.

Comment: No it isn't look closer you have `"px,"+","+"r` an extra comma in it and you are closing the background size with a comma not a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple background image you should use the following structure:

```
background-image:url(1), url(2), ...;
background-repeat: no-repeat(1), no-repeat(2) , ...;
background-size: 50% 50% (1),50% 50%(2) ,...;
background-position: left center(1), right center(2), ....;
```

OR

```
background: 
   url(1) 600px 10px no-repeat,  /* On top,    like z-index: 4; */
   url(2) 10px 10px no-repeat,   /*            like z-index: 3; */
   url(3);
```

Using JQuery

```
var top_header = '';
$(document).ready(function () {
    top_header = $('header');
});
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    top_header.css({
        'background-position': "left center," + "right " + (st * .5) + "px"
    });
});
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
    var bg = $("header").css('background-image');
    $("header").css('background-image', bg + ', url("http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/images_blogs/rawfile/2013/11/offset_RonnyRitschel_23712-1-660x660.jpg")');
});
```

In demo first click `Add bg` and scroll page to see result

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/rftmje5n/2/)

Comment: This is already working but the problem I have concerns the jQuery scroll function. It doesn't update the position on scroll. Please have a look at the two links in the question.